# Programatically scroll the .NET Browser Window

Tags: c#, javascript, scroll, browser

to be properly understood - this problem has the following accessory:

1. I have a page with lazy loader - which is activated when scrolling
2. Lazy loader is processed by JavaScript
3. At the end of the page that will load 100% - you will see a button that must be activated.

The following is an example of what I tried to write:

```
    _WebContent.wbThread1.Focus();
    int length = 100;

    new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= length; i++)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("{PGDN}");

                Thread.Sleep(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3));
                st.Start();
            }
        }).Start();
```

Everything is going well, but it is a problem to process event SendKey, wee need to focus region for the event, and in case the focus is lost will not spend anything.

---

I started to look for information on MSDN, and found something very interesting for processing the scrolling :

```
_WebContent.wbThread1.Document.Body.ScrollIntoView (true) / / allows scrolling to the top
_WebContent.wbThread1.Document.Body.ScrollIntoView (false) / / allows scrolling to the bottom
_WebContent.wbThread1.Document.Body.ScrollLeft = 100, / / sets the offset to the left
_WebContent.wbThread1.Document.Body.ScrollTop = 100, / / sets the upward shift
var rect = _WebContent.wbThread1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle; / / returns the current position
```

and this combination of features did not help. Theoretically code works, but in practice I did not had success with this example.

Event after I process scrolling, I will execute something like that:

```
HtmlElementCollection _HtmlElementCollect = _WebContent.wbThread1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("A");
foreach (HtmlElement link in _HtmlElementCollect)
            {
                if (link.InnerText.Equals("Load More..."))
                    link.InvokeMember("Click");
            }
```

**What suggestions do you have? How best can I do this scrolling?**

Answer (score 1):

you can scroll to the bottom by using

```
webCtrl.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, Int32.MaxValue);
```

Comment: I try this example, but is not working - maybe you have a complete example?

Comment: @Johnny Post your example where you try to call it and this didn't work